# Listing all country codes of phone numbers

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I'd like to have the country code list for phone numbers. Such as, United State (+1), United Kingdom (+44) ... I know that libphonenumber is a great tool to help phone parsing, formatting and validation. However, it doesn't seem to have the functionality for listing all country codes. But those data should be within the metadata in libphonenumber, right? Does anyone have experience on this?

Answer (score 30):

I am an android developer. I am using the libphonenumber library along with java.util.Locale class to complete this as follows. It may be late response, but hope it helps someone like me in future.

```
Set<String> set = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getSupportedRegions();

String[] arr = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", arr[i]);
    Log.d(TAG, "lib country:" + arr[i] + "  "+ locale.getDisplayCountry());
}
```

Comment: how do you get +44 out of this?

Comment: Is there a way to get the full name of the country from the phoneCode (+1, +91) or countryCode(US,IN)?

Answer (score 26):

Use the [`getSupportedRegions()`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/3db7670b42c4c03c3d69d9ed43cfe15fde978c5e/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.java#L953) method, then iterate these regions calling [`getCountryCodeForRegion()`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/3db7670b42c4c03c3d69d9ed43cfe15fde978c5e/java/libphonenumber/src/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.java#L2346).

Comment: The project moved to github, so the link is: http://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.8.11

Comment: Is there a way to get the full name of the country from the phoneCode (+1, +91) or countryCode(US,IN)?

Answer (score 18):

I generated json file with all country codes in the following format:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "code": "+7 840",
      "name": "Abkhazia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+93",
      "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+355",
      "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+213",
      "name": "Algeria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 684",
      "name": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+376",
      "name": "Andorra"
    },
    {
      "code": "+244",
      "name": "Angola"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 264",
      "name": "Anguilla"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 268",
      "name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+54",
      "name": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "code": "+374",
      "name": "Armenia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+297",
      "name": "Aruba"
    },
    {
      "code": "+247",
      "name": "Ascension"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+672",
      "name": "Australian External Territories"
    },
    {
      "code": "+43",
      "name": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+994",
      "name": "Azerbaijan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 242",
      "name": "Bahamas"
    },
    {
      "code": "+973",
      "name": "Bahrain"
    },
    {
      "code": "+880",
      "name": "Bangladesh"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 246",
      "name": "Barbados"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 268",
      "name": "Barbuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+375",
      "name": "Belarus"
    },
    {
      "code": "+32",
      "name": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "code": "+501",
      "name": "Belize"
    },
    {
      "code": "+229",
      "name": "Benin"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 441",
      "name": "Bermuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+975",
      "name": "Bhutan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+591",
      "name": "Bolivia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+387",
      "name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
    },
    {
      "code": "+267",
      "name": "Botswana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+55",
      "name": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "code": "+246",
      "name": "British Indian Ocean Territory"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 284",
      "name": "British Virgin Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+673",
      "name": "Brunei"
    },
    {
      "code": "+359",
      "name": "Bulgaria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+226",
      "name": "Burkina Faso"
    },
    {
      "code": "+257",
      "name": "Burundi"
    },
    {
      "code": "+855",
      "name": "Cambodia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+237",
      "name": "Cameroon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1",
      "name": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "code": "+238",
      "name": "Cape Verde"
    },
    {
      "code": "+ 345",
      "name": "Cayman Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+236",
      "name": "Central African Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+235",
      "name": "Chad"
    },
    {
      "code": "+56",
      "name": "Chile"
    },
    {
      "code": "+86",
      "name": "China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Christmas Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Cocos-Keeling Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+57",
      "name": "Colombia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+269",
      "name": "Comoros"
    },
    {
      "code": "+242",
      "name": "Congo"
    },
    {
      "code": "+243",
      "name": "Congo, Dem. Rep. of (Zaire)"
    },
    {
      "code": "+682",
      "name": "Cook Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+506",
      "name": "Costa Rica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+385",
      "name": "Croatia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+53",
      "name": "Cuba"
    },
    {
      "code": "+599",
      "name": "Curacao"
    },
    {
      "code": "+537",
      "name": "Cyprus"
    },
    {
      "code": "+420",
      "name": "Czech Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+45",
      "name": "Denmark"
    },
    {
      "code": "+246",
      "name": "Diego Garcia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+253",
      "name": "Djibouti"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 767",
      "name": "Dominica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 809",
      "name": "Dominican Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+670",
      "name": "East Timor"
    },
    {
      "code": "+56",
      "name": "Easter Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+593",
      "name": "Ecuador"
    },
    {
      "code": "+20",
      "name": "Egypt"
    },
    {
      "code": "+503",
      "name": "El Salvador"
    },
    {
      "code": "+240",
      "name": "Equatorial Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+291",
      "name": "Eritrea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+372",
      "name": "Estonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+251",
      "name": "Ethiopia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+500",
      "name": "Falkland Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+298",
      "name": "Faroe Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+679",
      "name": "Fiji"
    },
    {
      "code": "+358",
      "name": "Finland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+33",
      "name": "France"
    },
    {
      "code": "+596",
      "name": "French Antilles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+594",
      "name": "French Guiana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+689",
      "name": "French Polynesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+241",
      "name": "Gabon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+220",
      "name": "Gambia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+995",
      "name": "Georgia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+49",
      "name": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "code": "+233",
      "name": "Ghana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+350",
      "name": "Gibraltar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+30",
      "name": "Greece"
    },
    {
      "code": "+299",
      "name": "Greenland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 473",
      "name": "Grenada"
    },
    {
      "code": "+590",
      "name": "Guadeloupe"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 671",
      "name": "Guam"
    },
    {
      "code": "+502",
      "name": "Guatemala"
    },
    {
      "code": "+224",
      "name": "Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+245",
      "name": "Guinea-Bissau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+595",
      "name": "Guyana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+509",
      "name": "Haiti"
    },
    {
      "code": "+504",
      "name": "Honduras"
    },
    {
      "code": "+852",
      "name": "Hong Kong SAR China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+36",
      "name": "Hungary"
    },
    {
      "code": "+354",
      "name": "Iceland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+91",
      "name": "India"
    },
    {
      "code": "+62",
      "name": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+98",
      "name": "Iran"
    },
    {
      "code": "+964",
      "name": "Iraq"
    },
    {
      "code": "+353",
      "name": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+972",
      "name": "Israel"
    },
    {
      "code": "+39",
      "name": "Italy"
    },
    {
      "code": "+225",
      "name": "Ivory Coast"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 876",
      "name": "Jamaica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+81",
      "name": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+962",
      "name": "Jordan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+7 7",
      "name": "Kazakhstan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+254",
      "name": "Kenya"
    },
    {
      "code": "+686",
      "name": "Kiribati"
    },
    {
      "code": "+965",
      "name": "Kuwait"
    },
    {
      "code": "+996",
      "name": "Kyrgyzstan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+856",
      "name": "Laos"
    },
    {
      "code": "+371",
      "name": "Latvia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+961",
      "name": "Lebanon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+266",
      "name": "Lesotho"
    },
    {
      "code": "+231",
      "name": "Liberia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+218",
      "name": "Libya"
    },
    {
      "code": "+423",
      "name": "Liechtenstein"
    },
    {
      "code": "+370",
      "name": "Lithuania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+352",
      "name": "Luxembourg"
    },
    {
      "code": "+853",
      "name": "Macau SAR China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+389",
      "name": "Macedonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+261",
      "name": "Madagascar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+265",
      "name": "Malawi"
    },
    {
      "code": "+60",
      "name": "Malaysia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+960",
      "name": "Maldives"
    },
    {
      "code": "+223",
      "name": "Mali"
    },
    {
      "code": "+356",
      "name": "Malta"
    },
    {
      "code": "+692",
      "name": "Marshall Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+596",
      "name": "Martinique"
    },
    {
      "code": "+222",
      "name": "Mauritania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+230",
      "name": "Mauritius"
    },
    {
      "code": "+262",
      "name": "Mayotte"
    },
    {
      "code": "+52",
      "name": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "code": "+691",
      "name": "Micronesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 808",
      "name": "Midway Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+373",
      "name": "Moldova"
    },
    {
      "code": "+377",
      "name": "Monaco"
    },
    {
      "code": "+976",
      "name": "Mongolia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+382",
      "name": "Montenegro"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1664",
      "name": "Montserrat"
    },
    {
      "code": "+212",
      "name": "Morocco"
    },
    {
      "code": "+95",
      "name": "Myanmar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+264",
      "name": "Namibia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+674",
      "name": "Nauru"
    },
    {
      "code": "+977",
      "name": "Nepal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+31",
      "name": "Netherlands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+599",
      "name": "Netherlands Antilles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 869",
      "name": "Nevis"
    },
    {
      "code": "+687",
      "name": "New Caledonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+64",
      "name": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "code": "+505",
      "name": "Nicaragua"
    },
    {
      "code": "+227",
      "name": "Niger"
    },
    {
      "code": "+234",
      "name": "Nigeria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+683",
      "name": "Niue"
    },
    {
      "code": "+672",
      "name": "Norfolk Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+850",
      "name": "North Korea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 670",
      "name": "Northern Mariana Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+47",
      "name": "Norway"
    },
    {
      "code": "+968",
      "name": "Oman"
    },
    {
      "code": "+92",
      "name": "Pakistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+680",
      "name": "Palau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+970",
      "name": "Palestinian Territory"
    },
    {
      "code": "+507",
      "name": "Panama"
    },
    {
      "code": "+675",
      "name": "Papua New Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+595",
      "name": "Paraguay"
    },
    {
      "code": "+51",
      "name": "Peru"
    },
    {
      "code": "+63",
      "name": "Philippines"
    },
    {
      "code": "+48",
      "name": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+351",
      "name": "Portugal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 787",
      "name": "Puerto Rico"
    },
    {
      "code": "+974",
      "name": "Qatar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+262",
      "name": "Reunion"
    },
    {
      "code": "+40",
      "name": "Romania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+7",
      "name": "Russia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+250",
      "name": "Rwanda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+685",
      "name": "Samoa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+378",
      "name": "San Marino"
    },
    {
      "code": "+966",
      "name": "Saudi Arabia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+221",
      "name": "Senegal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+381",
      "name": "Serbia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+248",
      "name": "Seychelles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+232",
      "name": "Sierra Leone"
    },
    {
      "code": "+65",
      "name": "Singapore"
    },
    {
      "code": "+421",
      "name": "Slovakia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+386",
      "name": "Slovenia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+677",
      "name": "Solomon Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+27",
      "name": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+500",
      "name": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+82",
      "name": "South Korea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+34",
      "name": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "code": "+94",
      "name": "Sri Lanka"
    },
    {
      "code": "+249",
      "name": "Sudan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+597",
      "name": "Suriname"
    },
    {
      "code": "+268",
      "name": "Swaziland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+46",
      "name": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "code": "+41",
      "name": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+963",
      "name": "Syria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+886",
      "name": "Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+992",
      "name": "Tajikistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+255",
      "name": "Tanzania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+66",
      "name": "Thailand"
    },
    {
      "code": "+670",
      "name": "Timor Leste"
    },
    {
      "code": "+228",
      "name": "Togo"
    },
    {
      "code": "+690",
      "name": "Tokelau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+676",
      "name": "Tonga"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 868",
      "name": "Trinidad and Tobago"
    },
    {
      "code": "+216",
      "name": "Tunisia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+90",
      "name": "Turkey"
    },
    {
      "code": "+993",
      "name": "Turkmenistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 649",
      "name": "Turks and Caicos Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+688",
      "name": "Tuvalu"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 340",
      "name": "U.S. Virgin Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+256",
      "name": "Uganda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+380",
      "name": "Ukraine"
    },
    {
      "code": "+971",
      "name": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
      "code": "+44",
      "name": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1",
      "name": "United States"
    },
    {
      "code": "+598",
      "name": "Uruguay"
    },
    {
      "code": "+998",
      "name": "Uzbekistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+678",
      "name": "Vanuatu"
    },
    {
      "code": "+58",
      "name": "Venezuela"
    },
    {
      "code": "+84",
      "name": "Vietnam"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 808",
      "name": "Wake Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+681",
      "name": "Wallis and Futuna"
    },
    {
      "code": "+967",
      "name": "Yemen"
    },
    {
      "code": "+260",
      "name": "Zambia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+255",
      "name": "Zanzibar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+263",
      "name": "Zimbabwe"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the source code that generates the list? Or at least which method(s) from libphonenumber did you use?

Comment: Just looking at the top result of

"code": "+7 840",
"name": "Abkhazia"

It doesn't match Wikipedia or Google - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia

Answer (score 14):

I have use [libphonenumber](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements) in one of my project. For that we have list of country codes.

```
public static int findCountryCode(String countryShortCode) {

    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    return phoneUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion(countryShortCode.toUpperCase());

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Phonelibnumber **HAS** built-in method which returns a Set of supported country codes.
Just call `phoneNumberUtil.getSupportedCallingCodes()`.
(for instance, it will return you **1** for the US and **380** for Ukraine).
Then if you need you can iterate over them and get the region code:

```
String countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(codeFromThePreviousStep)
```

It will return you **US** and **UA** for the mentioned above countries.
If you need the country name - retrieve it from locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("", countryCode).
String countryName = locale.getDisplayCountry()
```

That will give you `United States` and `Ukraine` accordingly

Answer (score 6):

I generated country info using libphonenumber library and Locale class

add gradle dependency:
`implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.12'`

```
       for (countryCode in PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().supportedRegions) {
            val phoneCode = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getCountryCodeForRegion(countryCode)
            val displayCountry = Locale("", countryCode).displayCountry
            
            Log.e("#####", "+$phoneCode $countryCode $displayCountry")
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call `PhoneNumberUtil.getSupportedRegions()`. This will return an array of country codes ordered alphabetically.

```
[
  'AC',
  'AD',
  'AE',
  'AF',
  'AG',
  'AI',
  'AL',
  ...
  'GB',
  ...
  'ZZ'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using PhoneNumberUtil along with `java.util.Locale` for getting the country name.
You can import libphonenumber into your gradle file using: `implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.21'`
I wrote a code in Kotlin to output the region, country code, and country. so you can take a look at its output.

Code:

```
val phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
val set = phoneNumberUtil.supportedRegions
val arr = set.toTypedArray()

for (i in arr.indices) {
    val region = arr[i]
    val countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion(region)
    val locale = Locale("en", region)
    print("${region} $countryCode ${locale.displayCountry}\n")
}
```

The output (If you are interested to parse the text):

```
PR 1 Puerto Rico
PS 970 Palestine
PT 351 Portugal
PW 680 Palau
PY 595 Paraguay
QA 974 Qatar
AC 247 AC
AD 376 Andorra
AE 971 United Arab Emirates
AF 93 Afghanistan
AG 1 Antigua and Barbuda
AI 1 Anguilla
AL 355 Albania
AM 374 Armenia
AO 244 Angola
AR 54 Argentina
AS 1 American Samoa
AT 43 Austria
RE 262 Reunion
AU 61 Australia
AW 297 Aruba
AX 358 Åland Islands
AZ 994 Azerbaijan
RO 40 Romania
BA 387 Bosnia and Herzegovina
BB 1 Barbados
RS 381 Serbia
BD 880 Bangladesh
RU 7 Russia
BE 32 Belgium
BF 226 Burkina Faso
RW 250 Rwanda
BG 359 Bulgaria
BH 973 Bahrain
BI 257 Burundi
BJ 229 Benin
BL 590 Saint Barthélemy
BM 1 Bermuda
BN 673 Brunei
BO 591 Bolivia
SA 966 Saudi Arabia
BQ 599 Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba
SB 677 Solomon Islands
BR 55 Brazil
SC 248 Seychelles
BS 1 Bahamas
SD 249 Sudan
SE 46 Sweden
BT 975 Bhutan
SG 65 Singapore
BW 267 Botswana
SH 290 Saint Helena
SI 386 Slovenia
SJ 47 Svalbard And Jan Mayen
BY 375 Belarus
SK 421 Slovakia
BZ 501 Belize
SL 232 Sierra Leone
SM 378 San Marino
SN 221 Senegal
SO 252 Somalia
CA 1 Canada
SR 597 Suriname
CC 61 Cocos Islands
SS 211 South Sudan
ST 239 Sao Tome And Principe
CD 243 The Democratic Republic Of Congo
CF 236 Central African Republic
SV 503 El Salvador
CG 242 Congo
SX 1 Sint Maarten (Dutch part)
CH 41 Switzerland
CI 225 Côte d'Ivoire
SY 963 Syria
SZ 268 Swaziland
CK 682 Cook Islands
CL 56 Chile
CM 237 Cameroon
CN 86 China
CO 57 Colombia
TA 290 TA
TC 1 Turks And Caicos Islands
CR 506 Costa Rica
TD 235 Chad
CU 53 Cuba
TG 228 Togo
CV 238 Cape Verde
TH 66 Thailand
CW 599 Curaçao
CX 61 Christmas Island
CY 357 Cyprus
TJ 992 Tajikistan
TK 690 Tokelau
CZ 420 Czech Republic
TL 670 Timor-Leste
TM 993 Turkmenistan
TN 216 Tunisia
TO 676 Tonga
TR 90 Turkey
TT 1 Trinidad and Tobago
DE 49 Germany
TV 688 Tuvalu
TW 886 Taiwan
DJ 253 Djibouti
TZ 255 Tanzania
DK 45 Denmark
DM 1 Dominica
DO 1 Dominican Republic
UA 380 Ukraine
UG 256 Uganda
DZ 213 Algeria
US 1 United States
EC 593 Ecuador
EE 372 Estonia
EG 20 Egypt
EH 212 Western Sahara
UY 598 Uruguay
UZ 998 Uzbekistan
VA 39 Vatican
VC 1 Saint Vincent And The Grenadines
ER 291 Eritrea
ES 34 Spain
VE 58 Venezuela
ET 251 Ethiopia
VG 1 British Virgin Islands
VI 1 U.S. Virgin Islands
VN 84 Vietnam
VU 678 Vanuatu
FI 358 Finland
FJ 679 Fiji
FK 500 Falkland Islands
FM 691 Micronesia
FO 298 Faroe Islands
FR 33 France
WF 681 Wallis And Futuna
GA 241 Gabon
GB 44 United Kingdom
WS 685 Samoa
GD 1 Grenada
GE 995 Georgia
GF 594 French Guiana
GG 44 Guernsey
GH 233 Ghana
GI 350 Gibraltar
GL 299 Greenland
GM 220 Gambia
GN 224 Guinea
GP 590 Guadeloupe
GQ 240 Equatorial Guinea
GR 30 Greece
GT 502 Guatemala
GU 1 Guam
GW 245 Guinea-Bissau
GY 592 Guyana
XK 383 XK
HK 852 Hong Kong
HN 504 Honduras
HR 385 Croatia
YE 967 Yemen
HT 509 Haiti
HU 36 Hungary
ID 62 Indonesia
YT 262 Mayotte
IE 353 Ireland
IL 972 Israel
IM 44 Isle Of Man
IN 91 India
IO 246 British Indian Ocean Territory
ZA 27 South Africa
IQ 964 Iraq
IR 98 Iran
IS 354 Iceland
IT 39 Italy
ZM 260 Zambia
JE 44 Jersey
ZW 263 Zimbabwe
JM 1 Jamaica
JO 962 Jordan
JP 81 Japan
KE 254 Kenya
KG 996 Kyrgyzstan
KH 855 Cambodia
KI 686 Kiribati
KM 269 Comoros
KN 1 Saint Kitts And Nevis
KP 850 North Korea
KR 82 South Korea
KW 965 Kuwait
KY 1 Cayman Islands
KZ 7 Kazakhstan
LA 856 Laos
LB 961 Lebanon
LC 1 Saint Lucia
LI 423 Liechtenstein
LK 94 Sri Lanka
LR 231 Liberia
LS 266 Lesotho
LT 370 Lithuania
LU 352 Luxembourg
LV 371 Latvia
LY 218 Libya
MA 212 Morocco
MC 377 Monaco
MD 373 Moldova
ME 382 Montenegro
MF 590 Saint Martin
MG 261 Madagascar
MH 692 Marshall Islands
MK 389 Macedonia
ML 223 Mali
MM 95 Myanmar
MN 976 Mongolia
MO 853 Macao
MP 1 Northern Mariana Islands
MQ 596 Martinique
MR 222 Mauritania
MS 1 Montserrat
MT 356 Malta
MU 230 Mauritius
MV 960 Maldives
MW 265 Malawi
MX 52 Mexico
MY 60 Malaysia
MZ 258 Mozambique
NA 264 Namibia
NC 687 New Caledonia
NE 227 Niger
NF 672 Norfolk Island
NG 234 Nigeria
NI 505 Nicaragua
NL 31 Netherlands
NO 47 Norway
NP 977 Nepal
NR 674 Nauru
NU 683 Niue
NZ 64 New Zealand
OM 968 Oman
PA 507 Panama
PE 51 Peru
PF 689 French Polynesia
PG 675 Papua New Guinea
PH 63 Philippines
PK 92 Pakistan
PL 48 Poland
PM 508 Saint Pierre And Miquelon
```

Answer (score 1):

`libphonenumber-js` exports `getCountries` & `getCountryCallingCode`, so, you could simply:

```
const data = countries.map(countryCode => ({
    countryCode,
    dialingCode: getCountryCallingCode(currentCountryCode),
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the json data with all country details.

```
[{
    "NAME": "Afghanistan",
    "ISD": "93",
    "CODE1": "AFG",
    "CODE2": "AF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Albania",
    "ISD": "355",
    "CODE1": "ALB",
    "CODE2": "AL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Algeria",
    "ISD": "213",
    "CODE1": "DZA",
    "CODE2": "DZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "American Samoa",
    "ISD": "1684",
    "CODE1": "ASM",
    "CODE2": "AS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Andorra",
    "ISD": "376",
    "CODE1": "AND",
    "CODE2": "AD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Angola",
    "ISD": "244",
    "CODE1": "AGO",
    "CODE2": "AO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Anguilla",
    "ISD": "1264",
    "CODE1": "AIA",
    "CODE2": "AI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Antarctica",
    "ISD": "672",
    "CODE1": "ATA",
    "CODE2": "AQ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "ISD": "1268",
    "CODE1": "ATG",
    "CODE2": "AG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Argentina",
    "ISD": "54",
    "CODE1": "ARG",
    "CODE2": "AR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Armenia",
    "ISD": "374",
    "CODE1": "ARM",
    "CODE2": "AM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Aruba",
    "ISD": "297",
    "CODE1": "ABW",
    "CODE2": "AW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Australia",
    "ISD": "61",
    "CODE1": "AUS",
    "CODE2": "AU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Austria",
    "ISD": "43",
    "CODE1": "AUT",
    "CODE2": "AT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Azerbaijan",
    "ISD": "994",
    "CODE1": "AZE",
    "CODE2": "AZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bahamas",
    "ISD": "1242",
    "CODE1": "BHS",
    "CODE2": "BS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bahrain",
    "ISD": "973",
    "CODE1": "BHR",
    "CODE2": "BH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bangladesh",
    "ISD": "880",
    "CODE1": "BGD",
    "CODE2": "BD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Barbados",
    "ISD": "1246",
    "CODE1": "BRB",
    "CODE2": "BB"
},
{
    "NAME": "Belarus",
    "ISD": "375",
    "CODE1": "BLR",
    "CODE2": "BY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Belgium",
    "ISD": "32",
    "CODE1": "BEL",
    "CODE2": "BE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Belize",
    "ISD": "501",
    "CODE1": "BLZ",
    "CODE2": "BZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Benin",
    "ISD": "229",
    "CODE1": "BEN",
    "CODE2": "BJ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bermuda",
    "ISD": "1441",
    "CODE1": "BMU",
    "CODE2": "BM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bhutan",
    "ISD": "975",
    "CODE1": "BTN",
    "CODE2": "BT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bolivia",
    "ISD": "591",
    "CODE1": "BOL",
    "CODE2": "BO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "ISD": "387",
    "CODE1": "BIH",
    "CODE2": "BA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Botswana",
    "ISD": "267",
    "CODE1": "BWA",
    "CODE2": "BW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Brazil",
    "ISD": "55",
    "CODE1": "BRA",
    "CODE2": "BR"
},
{
    "NAME": "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "ISD": "246",
    "CODE1": "IOT",
    "CODE2": "IO"
},
{
    "NAME": "British Virgin Islands",
    "ISD": "1284",
    "CODE1": "VGB",
    "CODE2": "VG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Brunei",
    "ISD": "673",
    "CODE1": "BRN",
    "CODE2": "BN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Bulgaria",
    "ISD": "359",
    "CODE1": "BGR",
    "CODE2": "BG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Burkina Faso",
    "ISD": "226",
    "CODE1": "BFA",
    "CODE2": "BF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Myanmar",
    "ISD": "95",
    "CODE1": "MMR",
    "CODE2": "MM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Burundi",
    "ISD": "257",
    "CODE1": "BDI",
    "CODE2": "BI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cambodia",
    "ISD": "855",
    "CODE1": "KHM",
    "CODE2": "KH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cameroon",
    "ISD": "237",
    "CODE1": "CMR",
    "CODE2": "CM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Canada",
    "ISD": "1",
    "CODE1": "CAN",
    "CODE2": "CA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cape Verde",
    "ISD": "238",
    "CODE1": "CPV",
    "CODE2": "CV"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cayman Islands",
    "ISD": "1345",
    "CODE1": "CYM",
    "CODE2": "KY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Central African Republic",
    "ISD": "236",
    "CODE1": "CAF",
    "CODE2": "CF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Chad",
    "ISD": "235",
    "CODE1": "TCD",
    "CODE2": "TD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Chile",
    "ISD": "56",
    "CODE1": "CHL",
    "CODE2": "CL"
},
{
    "NAME": "China",
    "ISD": "86",
    "CODE1": "CHN",
    "CODE2": "CN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Christmas Island",
    "ISD": "61",
    "CODE1": "CXR",
    "CODE2": "CX"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cocos Islands",
    "ISD": "61",
    "CODE1": "CCK",
    "CODE2": "CC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Colombia",
    "ISD": "57",
    "CODE1": "COL",
    "CODE2": "CO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Comoros",
    "ISD": "269",
    "CODE1": "COM",
    "CODE2": "KM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Republic of the Congo",
    "ISD": "242",
    "CODE1": "COG",
    "CODE2": "CG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Democratic Republic of the Congo",
    "ISD": "243",
    "CODE1": "COD",
    "CODE2": "CD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cook Islands",
    "ISD": "682",
    "CODE1": "COK",
    "CODE2": "CK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Costa Rica",
    "ISD": "506",
    "CODE1": "CRI",
    "CODE2": "CR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Croatia",
    "ISD": "385",
    "CODE1": "HRV",
    "CODE2": "HR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cuba",
    "ISD": "53",
    "CODE1": "CUB",
    "CODE2": "CU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Curacao",
    "ISD": "599",
    "CODE1": "CUW",
    "CODE2": "CW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Cyprus",
    "ISD": "357",
    "CODE1": "CYP",
    "CODE2": "CY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Czech Republic",
    "ISD": "420",
    "CODE1": "CZE",
    "CODE2": "CZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Denmark",
    "ISD": "45",
    "CODE1": "DNK",
    "CODE2": "DK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Djibouti",
    "ISD": "253",
    "CODE1": "DJI",
    "CODE2": "DJ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Dominica",
    "ISD": "1767",
    "CODE1": "DMA",
    "CODE2": "DM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Dominican Republic",
    "ISD": "1809",
    "CODE1": "DOM",
    "CODE2": "DO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Dominican Republic",
    "ISD": "1829",
    "CODE1": "DOM",
    "CODE2": "DO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Dominican Republic",
    "ISD": "1849",
    "CODE1": "DOM",
    "CODE2": "DO"
},
{
    "NAME": "East Timor",
    "ISD": "670",
    "CODE1": "TLS",
    "CODE2": "TL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ecuador",
    "ISD": "593",
    "CODE1": "ECU",
    "CODE2": "EC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Egypt",
    "ISD": "20",
    "CODE1": "EGY",
    "CODE2": "EG"
},
{
    "NAME": "El Salvador",
    "ISD": "503",
    "CODE1": "SLV",
    "CODE2": "SV"
},
{
    "NAME": "Equatorial Guinea",
    "ISD": "240",
    "CODE1": "GNQ",
    "CODE2": "GQ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Eritrea",
    "ISD": "291",
    "CODE1": "ERI",
    "CODE2": "ER"
},
{
    "NAME": "Estonia",
    "ISD": "372",
    "CODE1": "EST",
    "CODE2": "EE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ethiopia",
    "ISD": "251",
    "CODE1": "ETH",
    "CODE2": "ET"
},
{
    "NAME": "Falkland Islands",
    "ISD": "500",
    "CODE1": "FLK",
    "CODE2": "FK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Faroe Islands",
    "ISD": "298",
    "CODE1": "FRO",
    "CODE2": "FO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Fiji",
    "ISD": "679",
    "CODE1": "FJI",
    "CODE2": "FJ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Finland",
    "ISD": "358",
    "CODE1": "FIN",
    "CODE2": "FI"
},
{
    "NAME": "France",
    "ISD": "33",
    "CODE1": "FRA",
    "CODE2": "FR"
},
{
    "NAME": "French Polynesia",
    "ISD": "689",
    "CODE1": "PYF",
    "CODE2": "PF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Gabon",
    "ISD": "241",
    "CODE1": "GAB",
    "CODE2": "GA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Gambia",
    "ISD": "220",
    "CODE1": "GMB",
    "CODE2": "GM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Georgia",
    "ISD": "995",
    "CODE1": "GEO",
    "CODE2": "GE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Germany",
    "ISD": "49",
    "CODE1": "DEU",
    "CODE2": "DE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ghana",
    "ISD": "233",
    "CODE1": "GHA",
    "CODE2": "GH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Gibraltar",
    "ISD": "350",
    "CODE1": "GIB",
    "CODE2": "GI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Greece",
    "ISD": "30",
    "CODE1": "GRC",
    "CODE2": "GR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Greenland",
    "ISD": "299",
    "CODE1": "GRL",
    "CODE2": "GL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Grenada",
    "ISD": "1473",
    "CODE1": "GRD",
    "CODE2": "GD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guam",
    "ISD": "1671",
    "CODE1": "GUM",
    "CODE2": "GU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guatemala",
    "ISD": "502",
    "CODE1": "GTM",
    "CODE2": "GT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guernsey",
    "ISD": "441481",
    "CODE1": "GGY",
    "CODE2": "GG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guinea",
    "ISD": "224",
    "CODE1": "GIN",
    "CODE2": "GN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guinea-Bissau",
    "ISD": "245",
    "CODE1": "GNB",
    "CODE2": "GW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Guyana",
    "ISD": "592",
    "CODE1": "GUY",
    "CODE2": "GY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Haiti",
    "ISD": "509",
    "CODE1": "HTI",
    "CODE2": "HT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Honduras",
    "ISD": "504",
    "CODE1": "HND",
    "CODE2": "HN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Hong Kong",
    "ISD": "852",
    "CODE1": "HKG",
    "CODE2": "HK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Hungary",
    "ISD": "36",
    "CODE1": "HUN",
    "CODE2": "HU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Iceland",
    "ISD": "354",
    "CODE1": "ISL",
    "CODE2": "IS"
},
{
    "NAME": "India",
    "ISD": "91",
    "CODE1": "IND",
    "CODE2": "IN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Indonesia",
    "ISD": "62",
    "CODE1": "IDN",
    "CODE2": "ID"
},
{
    "NAME": "Iran",
    "ISD": "98",
    "CODE1": "IRN",
    "CODE2": "IR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Iraq",
    "ISD": "964",
    "CODE1": "IRQ",
    "CODE2": "IQ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ireland",
    "ISD": "353",
    "CODE1": "IRL",
    "CODE2": "IE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Isle of Man",
    "ISD": "441624",
    "CODE1": "IMN",
    "CODE2": "IM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Israel",
    "ISD": "972",
    "CODE1": "ISR",
    "CODE2": "IL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Italy",
    "ISD": "39",
    "CODE1": "ITA",
    "CODE2": "IT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ivory Coast",
    "ISD": "225",
    "CODE1": "CIV",
    "CODE2": "CI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Jamaica",
    "ISD": "1876",
    "CODE1": "JAM",
    "CODE2": "JM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Japan",
    "ISD": "81",
    "CODE1": "JPN",
    "CODE2": "JP"
},
{
    "NAME": "Jersey",
    "ISD": "441534",
    "CODE1": "JEY",
    "CODE2": "JE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Jordan",
    "ISD": "962",
    "CODE1": "JOR",
    "CODE2": "JO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kazakhstan",
    "ISD": "7",
    "CODE1": "KAZ",
    "CODE2": "KZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kenya",
    "ISD": "254",
    "CODE1": "KEN",
    "CODE2": "KE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kiribati",
    "ISD": "686",
    "CODE1": "KIR",
    "CODE2": "KI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kosovo",
    "ISD": "383",
    "CODE1": "XKX",
    "CODE2": "XK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kuwait",
    "ISD": "965",
    "CODE1": "KWT",
    "CODE2": "KW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Kyrgyzstan",
    "ISD": "996",
    "CODE1": "KGZ",
    "CODE2": "KG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Laos",
    "ISD": "856",
    "CODE1": "LAO",
    "CODE2": "LA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Latvia",
    "ISD": "371",
    "CODE1": "LVA",
    "CODE2": "LV"
},
{
    "NAME": "Lebanon",
    "ISD": "961",
    "CODE1": "LBN",
    "CODE2": "LB"
},
{
    "NAME": "Lesotho",
    "ISD": "266",
    "CODE1": "LSO",
    "CODE2": "LS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Liberia",
    "ISD": "231",
    "CODE1": "LBR",
    "CODE2": "LR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Libya",
    "ISD": "218",
    "CODE1": "LBY",
    "CODE2": "LY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Liechtenstein",
    "ISD": "423",
    "CODE1": "LIE",
    "CODE2": "LI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Lithuania",
    "ISD": "370",
    "CODE1": "LTU",
    "CODE2": "LT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Luxembourg",
    "ISD": "352",
    "CODE1": "LUX",
    "CODE2": "LU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Macau",
    "ISD": "853",
    "CODE1": "MAC",
    "CODE2": "MO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Macedonia",
    "ISD": "389",
    "CODE1": "MKD",
    "CODE2": "MK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Madagascar",
    "ISD": "261",
    "CODE1": "MDG",
    "CODE2": "MG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Malawi",
    "ISD": "265",
    "CODE1": "MWI",
    "CODE2": "MW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Malaysia",
    "ISD": "60",
    "CODE1": "MYS",
    "CODE2": "MY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Maldives",
    "ISD": "960",
    "CODE1": "MDV",
    "CODE2": "MV"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mali",
    "ISD": "223",
    "CODE1": "MLI",
    "CODE2": "ML"
},
{
    "NAME": "Malta",
    "ISD": "356",
    "CODE1": "MLT",
    "CODE2": "MT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Marshall Islands",
    "ISD": "692",
    "CODE1": "MHL",
    "CODE2": "MH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mauritania",
    "ISD": "222",
    "CODE1": "MRT",
    "CODE2": "MR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mauritius",
    "ISD": "230",
    "CODE1": "MUS",
    "CODE2": "MU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mayotte",
    "ISD": "262",
    "CODE1": "MYT",
    "CODE2": "YT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mexico",
    "ISD": "52",
    "CODE1": "MEX",
    "CODE2": "MX"
},
{
    "NAME": "Micronesia",
    "ISD": "691",
    "CODE1": "FSM",
    "CODE2": "FM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Moldova",
    "ISD": "373",
    "CODE1": "MDA",
    "CODE2": "MD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Monaco",
    "ISD": "377",
    "CODE1": "MCO",
    "CODE2": "MC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mongolia",
    "ISD": "976",
    "CODE1": "MNG",
    "CODE2": "MN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Montenegro",
    "ISD": "382",
    "CODE1": "MNE",
    "CODE2": "ME"
},
{
    "NAME": "Montserrat",
    "ISD": "1664",
    "CODE1": "MSR",
    "CODE2": "MS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Morocco",
    "ISD": "212",
    "CODE1": "MAR",
    "CODE2": "MA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Mozambique",
    "ISD": "258",
    "CODE1": "MOZ",
    "CODE2": "MZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Namibia",
    "ISD": "264",
    "CODE1": "NAM",
    "CODE2": "NA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Nauru",
    "ISD": "674",
    "CODE1": "NRU",
    "CODE2": "NR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Nepal",
    "ISD": "977",
    "CODE1": "NPL",
    "CODE2": "NP"
},
{
    "NAME": "Netherlands",
    "ISD": "31",
    "CODE1": "NLD",
    "CODE2": "NL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Netherlands Antilles",
    "ISD": "599",
    "CODE1": "ANT",
    "CODE2": "AN"
},
{
    "NAME": "New Caledonia",
    "ISD": "687",
    "CODE1": "NCL",
    "CODE2": "NC"
},
{
    "NAME": "New Zealand",
    "ISD": "64",
    "CODE1": "NZL",
    "CODE2": "NZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Nicaragua",
    "ISD": "505",
    "CODE1": "NIC",
    "CODE2": "NI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Niger",
    "ISD": "227",
    "CODE1": "NER",
    "CODE2": "NE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Nigeria",
    "ISD": "234",
    "CODE1": "NGA",
    "CODE2": "NG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Niue",
    "ISD": "683",
    "CODE1": "NIU",
    "CODE2": "NU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "ISD": "1670",
    "CODE1": "MNP",
    "CODE2": "MP"
},
{
    "NAME": "North Korea",
    "ISD": "850",
    "CODE1": "PRK",
    "CODE2": "KP"
},
{
    "NAME": "Norway",
    "ISD": "47",
    "CODE1": "NOR",
    "CODE2": "NO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Oman",
    "ISD": "968",
    "CODE1": "OMN",
    "CODE2": "OM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Pakistan",
    "ISD": "92",
    "CODE1": "PAK",
    "CODE2": "PK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Palau",
    "ISD": "680",
    "CODE1": "PLW",
    "CODE2": "PW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Palestine",
    "ISD": "970",
    "CODE1": "PSE",
    "CODE2": "PS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Panama",
    "ISD": "507",
    "CODE1": "PAN",
    "CODE2": "PA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Papua New Guinea",
    "ISD": "675",
    "CODE1": "PNG",
    "CODE2": "PG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Paraguay",
    "ISD": "595",
    "CODE1": "PRY",
    "CODE2": "PY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Peru",
    "ISD": "51",
    "CODE1": "PER",
    "CODE2": "PE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Philippines",
    "ISD": "63",
    "CODE1": "PHL",
    "CODE2": "PH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Pitcairn",
    "ISD": "64",
    "CODE1": "PCN",
    "CODE2": "PN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Poland",
    "ISD": "48",
    "CODE1": "POL",
    "CODE2": "PL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Portugal",
    "ISD": "351",
    "CODE1": "PRT",
    "CODE2": "PT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Puerto Rico",
    "ISD": "1787",
    "CODE1": "PRI",
    "CODE2": "PR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Puerto Rico",
    "ISD": "1939",
    "CODE1": "PRI",
    "CODE2": "PR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Qatar",
    "ISD": "974",
    "CODE1": "QAT",
    "CODE2": "QA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Reunion",
    "ISD": "262",
    "CODE1": "REU",
    "CODE2": "RE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Romania",
    "ISD": "40",
    "CODE1": "ROU",
    "CODE2": "RO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Russia",
    "ISD": "7",
    "CODE1": "RUS",
    "CODE2": "RU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Rwanda",
    "ISD": "250",
    "CODE1": "RWA",
    "CODE2": "RW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Barthelemy",
    "ISD": "590",
    "CODE1": "BLM",
    "CODE2": "BL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Samoa",
    "ISD": "685",
    "CODE1": "WSM",
    "CODE2": "WS"
},
{
    "NAME": "San Marino",
    "ISD": "378",
    "CODE1": "SMR",
    "CODE2": "SM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "ISD": "239",
    "CODE1": "STP",
    "CODE2": "ST"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saudi Arabia",
    "ISD": "966",
    "CODE1": "SAU",
    "CODE2": "SA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Senegal",
    "ISD": "221",
    "CODE1": "SEN",
    "CODE2": "SN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Serbia",
    "ISD": "381",
    "CODE1": "SRB",
    "CODE2": "RS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Seychelles",
    "ISD": "248",
    "CODE1": "SYC",
    "CODE2": "SC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sierra Leone",
    "ISD": "232",
    "CODE1": "SLE",
    "CODE2": "SL"
},
{
    "NAME": "Singapore",
    "ISD": "65",
    "CODE1": "SGP",
    "CODE2": "SG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sint Maarten",
    "ISD": "1721",
    "CODE1": "SXM",
    "CODE2": "SX"
},
{
    "NAME": "Slovakia",
    "ISD": "421",
    "CODE1": "SVK",
    "CODE2": "SK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Slovenia",
    "ISD": "386",
    "CODE1": "SVN",
    "CODE2": "SI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Solomon Islands",
    "ISD": "677",
    "CODE1": "SLB",
    "CODE2": "SB"
},
{
    "NAME": "Somalia",
    "ISD": "252",
    "CODE1": "SOM",
    "CODE2": "SO"
},
{
    "NAME": "South Africa",
    "ISD": "27",
    "CODE1": "ZAF",
    "CODE2": "ZA"
},
{
    "NAME": "South Korea",
    "ISD": "82",
    "CODE1": "KOR",
    "CODE2": "KR"
},
{
    "NAME": "South Sudan",
    "ISD": "211",
    "CODE1": "SSD",
    "CODE2": "SS"
},
{
    "NAME": "Spain",
    "ISD": "34",
    "CODE1": "ESP",
    "CODE2": "ES"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sri Lanka",
    "ISD": "94",
    "CODE1": "LKA",
    "CODE2": "LK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Helena",
    "ISD": "290",
    "CODE1": "SHN",
    "CODE2": "SH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    "ISD": "1869",
    "CODE1": "KNA",
    "CODE2": "KN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Lucia",
    "ISD": "1758",
    "CODE1": "LCA",
    "CODE2": "LC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Martin",
    "ISD": "590",
    "CODE1": "MAF",
    "CODE2": "MF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "ISD": "508",
    "CODE1": "SPM",
    "CODE2": "PM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
    "ISD": "1784",
    "CODE1": "VCT",
    "CODE2": "VC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sudan",
    "ISD": "249",
    "CODE1": "SDN",
    "CODE2": "SD"
},
{
    "NAME": "Suriname",
    "ISD": "597",
    "CODE1": "SUR",
    "CODE2": "SR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
    "ISD": "47",
    "CODE1": "SJM",
    "CODE2": "SJ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Swaziland",
    "ISD": "268",
    "CODE1": "SWZ",
    "CODE2": "SZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Sweden",
    "ISD": "46",
    "CODE1": "SWE",
    "CODE2": "SE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Switzerland",
    "ISD": "41",
    "CODE1": "CHE",
    "CODE2": "CH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Syria",
    "ISD": "963",
    "CODE1": "SYR",
    "CODE2": "SY"
},
{
    "NAME": "Taiwan",
    "ISD": "886",
    "CODE1": "TWN",
    "CODE2": "TW"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tajikistan",
    "ISD": "992",
    "CODE1": "TJK",
    "CODE2": "TJ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tanzania",
    "ISD": "255",
    "CODE1": "TZA",
    "CODE2": "TZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Thailand",
    "ISD": "66",
    "CODE1": "THA",
    "CODE2": "TH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Togo",
    "ISD": "228",
    "CODE1": "TGO",
    "CODE2": "TG"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tokelau",
    "ISD": "690",
    "CODE1": "TKL",
    "CODE2": "TK"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tonga",
    "ISD": "676",
    "CODE1": "TON",
    "CODE2": "TO"
},
{
    "NAME": "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "ISD": "1868",
    "CODE1": "TTO",
    "CODE2": "TT"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tunisia",
    "ISD": "216",
    "CODE1": "TUN",
    "CODE2": "TN"
},
{
    "NAME": "Turkey",
    "ISD": "90",
    "CODE1": "TUR",
    "CODE2": "TR"
},
{
    "NAME": "Turkmenistan",
    "ISD": "993",
    "CODE1": "TKM",
    "CODE2": "TM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Turks and Caicos Islands",
    "ISD": "1649",
    "CODE1": "TCA",
    "CODE2": "TC"
},
{
    "NAME": "Tuvalu",
    "ISD": "688",
    "CODE1": "TUV",
    "CODE2": "TV"
},
{
    "NAME": "United Arab Emirates",
    "ISD": "971",
    "CODE1": "ARE",
    "CODE2": "AE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Uganda",
    "ISD": "256",
    "CODE1": "UGA",
    "CODE2": "UG"
},
{
    "NAME": "United Kingdom",
    "ISD": "44",
    "CODE1": "GBR",
    "CODE2": "GB"
},
{
    "NAME": "Ukraine",
    "ISD": "380",
    "CODE1": "UKR",
    "CODE2": "UA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Uruguay",
    "ISD": "598",
    "CODE1": "URY",
    "CODE2": "UY"
},
{
    "NAME": "United States",
    "ISD": "1",
    "CODE1": "USA",
    "CODE2": "US"
},
{
    "NAME": "Uzbekistan",
    "ISD": "998",
    "CODE1": "UZB",
    "CODE2": "UZ"
},
{
    "NAME": "Vanuatu",
    "ISD": "678",
    "CODE1": "VUT",
    "CODE2": "VU"
},
{
    "NAME": "Vatican",
    "ISD": "379",
    "CODE1": "VAT",
    "CODE2": "VA"
},
{
    "NAME": "Venezuela",
    "ISD": "58",
    "CODE1": "VEN",
    "CODE2": "VE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Vietnam",
    "ISD": "84",
    "CODE1": "VNM",
    "CODE2": "VN"
},
{
    "NAME": "U.S. Virgin Islands",
    "ISD": "1340",
    "CODE1": "VIR",
    "CODE2": "VI"
},
{
    "NAME": "Wallis and Futuna",
    "ISD": "681",
    "CODE1": "WLF",
    "CODE2": "WF"
},
{
    "NAME": "Western Sahara",
    "ISD": "212",
    "CODE1": "ESH",
    "CODE2": "EH"
},
{
    "NAME": "Yemen",
    "ISD": "967",
    "CODE1": "YEM",
    "CODE2": "YE"
},
{
    "NAME": "Zambia",
    "ISD": "260",
    "CODE1": "ZMB",
    "CODE2": "ZM"
},
{
    "NAME": "Zimbabwe",
    "ISD": "263",
    "CODE1": "ZWE",
    "CODE2": "ZW"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/mledoze/countries/blob/master/) is a resource with country codes, country names, etc.

Note that `phoneUtil.getCountryCodeForRegion` returns "1" for [North American Numbering Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) countries such as Barbados, which is incorrect.

Comment: Well *technically* that seems to be right as the country code *is* only 1.
The next 3 digits don't technically belong the country code.
Cf. https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/issues/1501

Though that's not what most people would expect to get back and is not helpful in most use case, either.