# Listing All Countries With Codes and Calling Codes using libPhoneNumber on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, libphonenumber

I came across this [Stackoverflow Thread about listing countries and it's calling codes using libPhoneNumber library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803432/listing-all-country-codes-of-phone-numbers)

The solution is this

> Use the `getSupportedRegions()` method, then iterate these regions calling `getCountryCodeForRegion()`.

However, the accepted solution does not apply on the iOS version of libPhoneNumber. `getSupportedRegions()`  is not available on the iOS version

Any idea to do this in **iOS** **using libPhoneNumber**?

Answer (score 1):

solution is :

```
import libPhoneNumber_iOS


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let phoneUtil = NBPhoneNumberUtil()
    let regions = phoneUtil.getSupportedRegions()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class with a method which returns a NSSet or NSDictionary of Country Code and Country String.

[Country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code) can be found on wikipedia.